# How to install plugins to Sublime Text 2 editor?

Tags: plugins, installation, sublimetext2

How to **install plugins** to the Sublime Text editor?

I would like to install **Emmet plugin** to Sublime Text 2 editor.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

You should have a `Data/Packages` folder in your Sublime Text 2 install directory.
All you need to do is download the plugin and put the plugin folder in the `Packages` folder.

Or, an easier way would be to install the `Package Control Plugin` by wbond.

Just go here: https://sublime.wbond.net/installation

and follow the install instructions.

Once you are done you can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> shortcut in Sublime, type in install and press enter, then search for `emmet`.

EDIT: You can now also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> right away and use the command 'Install Package Control' instead of following the install instructions. (Tested on Build 3126)

Comment: Note that - in Sublime 3, at least - you can locate the `Packages` folder by going to the *Preferences* menu in Sublime and selecting *Browse Packages...*.

Answer (score 59):

Install the [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation) first.

The simplest method of installation is through the Sublime Text console. The console is accessed via the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> shortcut or the View > Show Console menu. Once open, paste the appropriate Python code for your version of Sublime Text into the console.

**Code for Sublime Text 3**

```
import urllib.request,os; pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); open(os.path.join(ipp, pf), 'wb').write(urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://sublime.wbond.net/' + pf.replace(' ','%20')).read())
```

**Code for Sublime Text 2**

```
import urllib2,os; pf='Package Control.sublime-package'; ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); os.makedirs( ipp ) if not os.path.exists(ipp) else None; urllib2.install_opener( urllib2.build_opener( urllib2.ProxyHandler( ))); open( os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write( urllib2.urlopen( 'http://sublime.wbond.net/' +pf.replace( ' ','%20' )).read()); print( 'Please restart Sublime Text to finish installation')
```

> For the up-to-date installation code, please check [Package Control Installation Guide](https://packagecontrol.io/installation).

**Manual**

If for some reason the console installation instructions do not work for you (such as having a proxy on your network), perform the following steps to manually install Package Control:

1. Click the Preferences > Browse Packages… menu
2. Browse up a folder and then into the Installed Packages/ folder
3. Download Package Control.sublime-package and copy it into the
   Installed Packages/ directory
4. Restart Sublime Text

**[Usage](https://sublime.wbond.net/docs/usage)**

Package Control is driven by the Command Pallete. To open the pallete, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> (Win, Linux) or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> (OSX). All Package Control commands begin with Package Control:, so start by typing Package.

Comment: May be a solution but is certainly the dumbest thing I've ever heard of. Install an installer in order to install packages.

Comment: From https://packagecontrol.io/installation: WARNING: Please do not redistribute the install code via another website. It will change with every release. Instead, please link to this page.

Comment: @Zenadix It's true, however SE has Warning that link-only answers are not allowed, therefore if you think the code is out-dated, edit the question and post the updated code. In my answer there are no any hardcoded versions, so I think it should work.

Answer (score 11):

### Without Package Manager

*I highly recommend using the Package Manager as described in other answers as it's far more convenient for both installing **and** updating. However, sometimes plugins are not in the directory, so here is the manual approach.*

First off, find your `Packages` directory in your `Application Support/Sublime Text 2` directory, for example:

`~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages`

Now, take your Plugin folder (which you can download as a zip from GitHub, for example) and simply copy the folder into your `Packages` directory:

```
cp ~/Downloads/SomePlugin-master/ 
   ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 2/Packages/SomePlugin`
```

Restart Sublime Text 2 and boom! you're done.

### With Package Manager

Refer to one of the other answers here or go to the [Package Manager home page](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control).

### Bonus Points

If there's a plugin that isn't in the Package Manager, why not submit it on behalf of the author by following the steps found [here](https://sublime.wbond.net/docs/submitting_a_package).

Answer (score 10):

1. Install the Package Manager as directed on https://packagecontrol.io/installation
2. Open the Package Manager using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
3. Type **Package Control** to show related commands (Install Package, Remove Package etc.) with packages

Enjoy it!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to install Package Control first (from the Python console in Sublime. Visit http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control for more info), and then install emmet from their repository.

Answer (score 1):

According to John Day's answer

You should have a **Data/Packages folder** in your Sublime Text 2 install directory. All you need to do is download the plugin and put the plugin folder in the Packages folder.

*In case if you are searching for Data/Packages folder you can find it here*

**Windows**: %APPDATA%\Sublime Text 2

**OS X**: ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2

**Linux**: ~/.Sublime Text 2

**Portable Installation**: Sublime Text 2/Data

Answer (score 1):

> The instruction has been tested on Mac OSx Catalina.

After installing `Sublime Text 3`, install `Package Control` through `Tools > Package Control`.
Use the following instructions to install `package` or `theme`:

1. press `CMD + SHIFT + P`
2. choose `Package Control: Install Package`---or any other options you require.
   [image: package control]
3. enter the name of required package or theme and press enter.

[image: installing package]

Answer (score 0):

Installation code chunks for vanilla Sublime may change in the future.

This [link](https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st2) would be the safest place to install plugin support to Sublime Text 2.

For Sublime Text 3 this [link](https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st3) works has the code.

[image]