# How to format django template in Sublime Text

Tags: django, sublimetext2, code-formatting, pycharm

How can one format django template in Sublime Text. 
My template consists of:

1. **HTML** (django template language with `{{ variable }}` and `{% stuff %}`)
2. **javascript**

Is there a way to get same kind of formatting PyCharm provides?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This package should help:
https://github.com/squ1b3r/Djaneiro

Here are some tips on install:
[How to install plugins to Sublime Text 2 editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652758/install-plugins-to-sublimetext-2)

Comment: i do not see syntax in javascript section

Comment: There is an error in this plugin, it uses {# #} to comment multiple lines in html templates which won't comment out anything. Instead, you are supposed to use the comment tag.

Comment: I wasn't sure about Djaneiro at first but after using it for a while I found it extremely helpful. The improved syntax highlighting for Django templates is awesome. I ended up writing a quick review and feature walkthrough for it: https://dbader.org/blog/sublime-text-djaneiro-review

Answer (score 5):

A couple different things:

[Djanerio](https://github.com/squ1b3r/Djaneiro) has a nice set of auto-completion and color schemes specific to Django. Check out their README file to see the list of available substitutions

[JSFormat](https://github.com/jdc0589/JsFormat) is also great for javascript in ST2, for your templates

[Colorpicker](http://weslly.github.io/ColorPicker/) offers a generic css color sheet that you can tinker with. This comes in handy for things all of the above doesn't pick up on.