# Django template tag formatter for Sublimetext

Tags: sublimetext3

I am working in Django HTML templates using SublimeText 3.

Is there any easy way to format and indent matching `{%` blocks? None of the usual suspects such as `HTMLPrettify` seem to support this.

E.g, I want this code:

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
{% for field in obj.meta.fields %}
    <th scope="col">
    {{ field.verbose_name }}
    </th>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

To become this code:

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
    {% for field in obj.meta.fields %}
        <th scope="col">
            {{ field.verbose_name }}
        </th>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: can this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218664/how-to-format-django-template-in-sublime-text

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan No, Dajeneiro doesn't format code...