# Why is Sublime Package Control not working?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin, package-control

I have already installed **Sublime Text 2**, and following [this guide](https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st2), I installed the *Package Control*; once that I used the `Ctrl + Shift + P` shortcut in Sublime, and when I type *install*, the option is not there for installing.

I don't want to install manually all the plugins, that would be a nightmare.

Comment: Why are you not using Sublime Text 3? It's basically stable even tho it says beta.

Comment: Do you have a network monitor running i.e. little snitch.

Comment: Not sure but see if thread can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652758/how-to-install-plugins-to-sublime-text-2-editor

Comment: @Marwelln Hey, i tried Sublime 3 too, and i have the same issue.

Comment: What operation system are you using?

Comment: Elementary OS Luna, i have been using it for two years, and always worked fine, but 2 days ago, the sublime Package Controll has stopped working.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm sure that your **Package Control** is ignored, i had the same problem time ago, just go to `Preferences -> Settings - User`, and remove `Package Control` from the list of ignored packages.

See this -> [Package Control no longer showing up in Sublime Text 3](https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues/874)

Comment: You are a genius! Thanks a lot, that was the problem and now it is working normal :)

Comment: I would like to have a coffee with the guy that decided to disable it :)

Comment: Yeah.. why disable it? I think the Package Control website's installation instructions should add a note about this