# How do I change opening and closing tag at the same time in Sublime Text 3

Tags: tags, sublimetext3, multi-select

**What is the easiest way to change the opening and closing code tag?**
I especially need a way to do it using **Sublime Text 3**'s **Multi-Select**... so I don't have to change it 1,000 times. And **find and replace won't work because I need to change only specific matches**.

*EX: CHANGE ALL DIVs with class="item" to tr tags*
*(ignore my improperly formated code this is for example only)*

```
<div class="item">foo foo bar is foofoobar</div>
<div class="item">bar foo is barfoo</div>
<div> not a match for .item</div>
<div class="item">foo bar foo is foobarfoo</div>
```

BECOMES

```
<tr class="item">foo foo bar is foofoobar</tr>
<tr class="item">bar foo is barfoo</tr>
<div> not a match for .item</div>
<tr class="item">foo bar foo is foobarfoo</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the answer so I'm answering my own question.
**What is the easiest way to change the opening and closing code tag?**
I especially need a way to do it using **Sublime Text 3**'s **Multi-Select**... so I don't have to change it 1,000 times. And **find and replace won't work because I need to change only specific matches**.

HERE GOES - THE ANSWER :

1. **Install Emmet**
2. Then select the opening tag you want to change. 
   (if you need to multi select -->) Hit *ALT + F3*.
3. Now (with Emmet installed) hit ***CTRL + SHIFT + u***
4. Now **change your tag and hit enter**/return

*EX: CHANGE ALL DIVs with class="item" to tr tags*
*(ignore my improperly formated code this is for example only)*

```
<div class="item">foo foo bar is foofoobar</div>
<div class="item">bar foo is barfoo</div>
<div> not a match for .item</div>
<div class="item">foo bar foo is foobarfoo</div>
```

1. Highlight div class="item"
2. hit ALT + F3 to select all matching divs
3. hit CTRL + SHIFT + u
4. type "tr" and hit enter

DONE PRESTO MAGICO

```
<tr class="item">foo foo bar is foofoobar</tr>
<tr class="item">bar foo is barfoo</tr>
<div> not a match for .item</div>
<tr class="item">foo bar foo is foobarfoo</tr>
```

**POSSIBLE ISSUES:**

**Package Control not working** 
I had to uninstall Package Control before installing Emmet as my Package Control had become corrupt somehow.
**Solution:**
This post answers the question of how to fix a corrupt package control item.
[Why is Sublime Package Control not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461198/why-is-sublime-package-control-not-working)

**Wrong Shortcode**
It is possible your shortcode is conflicted with another plugin or your shortcode has changed from the default assignment.
**Solution:**
Go to

> Preferences > Package Settings > Emmet > Key Bindings - Default

Look for "update_as_you_type" and check the "keys" assigned. This is the keyboard shortcut you should be using. If that still does not work. Try changing the key assignment.