# How to install a program from GitHub?

Tags: github, sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

I am very new to GitHub. Recently I downloaded a program for printing in Sublime Text from GitHub. Here is the link: https://github.com/svenax/SublimePrint
But after I downloaded the program called SublimePrint-master.zip, I don't know how to install it in windows. It doesn't look like there is a setup file or installation file after I unzipped SublimePrint-master.zip. Would anyone give me a hint how to install a program from GitHub? Many thanks.

Comment: Look for a readme (well-behaved projects should provide one). There's not a universal way to install packages.

Answer (score 4):

GitHub is not a store app. There is no "guide on how to install an a program from github". Github is a platform where developers put their code*. **Any code**. It could be a Windows program. It could be an Android program. It could be html. It could be a library. It could be a snippet of code. It could be code in a language invented by the developer. It could be his shopping list.

Some repositories have a Readme that guides how to compile or install the program. But that is just up to the developers that posted the code. If there isn't a readme then try to figure out what kind of code it is (e.g. a Sublime plugin) and search the web how to install that kind of code.

(*) it's more than that, but for the purposes of the question let's limit to this

Answer (score 3):

See this answer for how to install Sublime plugins: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15652795/4494

The plugin also contains a file `INSTALL.txt`, which should be a good start to read about, well, *installing it*: https://github.com/svenax/SublimePrint/blob/master/INSTALL.txt